# Best way to manage pages by language/location US/PT (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, location

Our platform runs in Drupal and we want to show different pages taking in consideration the users location (US or PT/Brazil).
The features would change.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a little. it is very general

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to explain, you have to install modules like:
   Content translation and locale
after that you have to add languages in configuration, and you need set in content type.

more detail you can view this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sx9lJ_hOrCw
or you can search multi language in youtube.